# Reverse loop inside a loop with same list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, reverse

```
num = list(str(1234567))

for n1 in num:
    print(n1)
    for n2 in reversed(num):
        print('\t', n2)
```

On each iteration, it prints the first digit from the first loop and all 7 from the reverse loop. How can I print not all digits but only the last (i.e first) digit from reverse loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest way is to just zip the forward and reverse lists together:

```
for n1, n2 in zip(num, reversed(num)):
    print(n1, '\t', n2)
```

Comment: izip = zip and %d = %s here. Yea, great solution.

Comment: Need `from itertools import izip`, but this also works with just `zip()`.

Comment: I have to use Java and I think what you did was sufficiently advanced technology.

Comment: @Nimbuz, as ezod said, izip is from itertools. The difference is that it's more memory efficient if you have large lists. It doesn't create the whole list in one go, but instead generates it an element at a time.

Comment: Ok great, I didn't even know it existed, I thought it was a typo. :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's a feeble attempt. Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

```
 for idx,i in enumerate(x):
     print(i,"\t",x[-(idx+1)])
```

Comment: `enumerate` returns a list of tuples each element of which is the index (which I often abbreviate to idx) and the element. `enumerate("abc") => [(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]`

Comment: Oh great, nice to know about that, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
num = list(str(1234567))
for i in range(len(num)):
    print(num[i], '\t', num[-(i+1)])
```

Output is:

```
1       7                       
2       6                       
3       5                       
4       4                       
5       3                       
6       2                       
7       1
```

Comment: What does "num[-(i+1)]" do? and why not just "for i in num"?

Comment: `for i in num` iterates over num (touches every element in `num`). `num[-(i+1)]` is lookup of a specific element by index.

Comment: The negative index means to start from the end of the list. The `i+1` is necessary because, for example, `num[-1]` is the last item in the list, yet the forward indexing (and thus, the range of values of `i`) begins with 0.

Using `for i in num` will make `i` equal to the value of one of the items in `num` at each iteration, as opposed to the list index. `range(len(num))` by contrast returns (basically) a list of indices for `num`.

Comment: Great, learnt a lot of new things from this one simple example, thanks all! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a second list:

```
>>> num_rev = num[:]
>>> num_rev.reverse()
>>> num_rev
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Then do something like:

```
>>> for n1,n2 in zip(num,num_rev): 
...     print(n1, n2)
... 
0 9
1 8
2 7
3 6
4 5
5 4
6 3
7 2
8 1
9 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Python, but here it is in Haskell :)

```
myDie  = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
sevens = [ (x,y) | x <- myDie, y <- myDie, x+y == 7]
```

Comment: Okay, but why weird variable names? :)